# Django, Gunicorn Setup

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to setup a django project on my server and cannot get it to run. I am using virtualenv, gunicorn and nginx for static files. I am not sure were I am going wrong. My current setup is as follows:

```
myenv
  - project(my django project)
  - bin(and all it contains)
  - lib(and all it contains)
  - include(and all it contains)
  - gunicorn_config.py
```

gunicorn_config.py:

```
command = '/home/me/django/myenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/me/django/myenv/project'
bind = '127.0.0.1:80'
workers = 2
```

nginx project.conf:

```
upstream project_server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn_project.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name project.com www.project.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /home/me/django/myenv/assets;

    location / {
        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://project_server;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/me/django/myenv/project/project/templates;
    }
}
```

And I run the following to try start it all up:

```
/home/me/django/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/me/django/myenv/gunicorn_config.py project/project/wsgi.py
```

But it just says "Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 80)"

Comment: Arent both gunicorn and nginx on 80?   You need to use another port for gunicorn.

Comment: This looks reasonably close to what you need   Note gunicorn is on 8000.  Start out ignoringting out a lot of stuff like the statics.  You really care about the proxy_pass directive at this point. http://goodcode.io/articles/django-nginx-gunicorn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured gunicorn to bind on a TCP port, but gunicorn is binding on a unix socket. You should use the same thing; preferably the socket, so it doesn't conflict with the port nginx is actually listening on.

In gunicorn_config.py:

```
bind = 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn_project.sock'
```

Comment: I changed the bind option, but now when I run "/home/me/django/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/me/django/myenv/gunicorn_config.py project/project/wsgi.py" it says "Exception in worker process:"....."ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'project/project/wsgi:application'?"

Comment: Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: Did you try changing it as the error message suggested?

Comment: Sounds like either a python path or gunicorn param issue. Re python path, have you activated your virtualenv in this bash session?

Comment: my own gunicorn command line looks like **gunicorn websec.wsgi**.  where **I've already cd'ed into the directory where manage.py** is to be found and websec is my "main app" under that directory where wsgi.py sits.  mind you, it doesn't hurt to specify the full path to gunicorn, but I wouldnt be surprised that setting your current directory would solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I have my virtualenv activated. It does seem to be a python path issue, saying it can't find the application, but my env is activated and I am specifying the path "pythonpath = '/home/me/django/myenv/project'" on the gunicorn_config.py so I do not know the solution. I will keep trying to figure it out and report back when I get to the bottom of it.

Comment: "ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'project/wsgi:application'?"

Comment: So as I said, what happens if you follow that advice?

Comment: I did try it yesterday using "/home/me/sites/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/me/sites/myenv/gunicorn_config.py project/wsgi:application" and it did not work, I just tried "/home/me/sites/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/me/sites/myenv/gunicorn_config.py project.wsgi:application"....using ".wsgi" instead of "/wsgi" and it has ran without any errors. But this leaves a session open in terminal, how can I keep it running even when I logout?

Comment: Everything works now, I see the django welcome page, but I have to leave the session open in terminal, how can I keep it on even when I close out of the terminal session? i have a rails site that uses unicorn and I run "unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production" and it stays on.

Comment: You need to run gunicorn as a service.  That means you have to tell another program to run gunicorn and keep it running.  Depending on your os (assuming Linux) that could be upstart, systemd, runit or monit.  Sorry, that's another thing for you to research, but it falls well outside the scope of your question here.  I use runit to launch the service and monit to monitor it - monit's start/stop are calls to runit.  Monit by itself works fine too, you just have to write your own gunicorn demonization command, I think.

Comment: Actually you have a look at whats running rails on your other site and use that.  If it ain't a terminal its likely a service and you've got a service supervisor looking after it.  Django itself is often hooked up to supervisord.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I would guess nginx spins up before gunicorn.  It takes port 80 (from your **listen**).  gunicorn comes next, also wants port 80 (from your **bind**), and finds it occupied so it errors out.  Run gunicorn on a different port and use proxy_pass to tell nginx about it.

Gunicorn

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
```

Nginx

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
```

Comment: I updated nginx conf file so the line is "listen 8000;". I changed my gunicorn bind setting to below.